# make requests to existing request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm implementing a route which called by the frontend, adds some answer to the database and I want this route to be able to call another route related to another table in the DB when some condition is fulfilled (e.g. `lastAnswer === true`) e.g.

File 1 (e.g. adds information about the button pressed to the db)

```js
route.post('/add', (req, res) => {
       ...
       add the answer to the db
       ...
       if (req.body.lastAnswer === true) {
           call another route (e.g. '/calculate/:testId)
       }

})
```

File 2

```js
route.post('/calculate/:testId', (req, res) => {
         ...
         calculateSth and add to the other table
         ...
})
```

I'm wondering what's the best (recommended) way to make such a related request.

Comment: instead of calling the second route, why not make a function of the logic in the second route?

Comment: So that it would look like: 
route.post('/add)... => { ... if(req.body.lastAnswer === true) { calculateScore(testId); } }
route.post('/calculate/:testId', (req, res) => { calcualeScore(testId); } ?

Comment: the `calculateSth and add to the other table` logic should be a function that you can call inside both the routes. If that is what is inside calculateScore then yes, your above code should be fine